# Block http/https requests executed from scripts or any other external sources in node server

Tags: node.js, http, express, https

In node, if I use a library like axios and a simple async script, I can send unlimited post requests to any web server. If I know all parameters, headers and cookies needed for that url, I'll get a success response.

Also, anyone can easily make those requests using Postman.

I already use CORS in my node servers to block requests coming from different origins, but that works only for other websites triggering requests in browsers.

I'd like to know if it's possible to completely block requests from external sources (manually created scripts, postman, softwares like LOIC, etc...) in a node server using express.

thanks!

Comment: Use a firewall?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes, a firewall would be a good strategy, but how can I differ a legitimate request from a malicious request?

Comment: I already have rate-limiters and jwt verifications to prevent from requests abusing, but I just can't see how a firewall would help me here.

Comment: Perhaps you should first define (for yourself, but especially for the people you're asking your question to) what a "legitimate request" is :D Because right now, I'm reading "how can I completely block requests from external sources", which for me means _any_ external source, not just "illegitimate external sources".

Comment: Thanks for your observation! Legitimate requests are those that comes only from my website.

Comment: I think this is not possible, because post requests are actually coming from my users devices, and not "from my site", and the blocking of illegitimate requests should be mine and only mine responsability, by using authentication, validation and rate-limiting mechanisms... am I right?

Comment: In short: yes, you're right.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm thinking about implementing an ip filtering mechanism in a DB level that blacklists all fraudulent ips, and check if the ip doesn't exist in the DB before accessing a particular route. What do you think about this approach?

Comment: That might be an option, although it would require lots of administration. If your site is well-implemented, "fraudulent ips" just wouldn't be able to do a whole lot of damage to it, even _if_ they aren't blocked (also because you can only block an IP if it's too late and it has already misbehaved).

Comment: How do you define a legitimate request?  How do you define a request you want to block?  We can't help you without knowing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to know if it's possible to completely block requests from external sources (manually created scripts, postman, softwares like LOIC, etc...) in a node server using express.

No, it is not possible.  A well formed request from postman or coded with axios in node.js can be made to look exactly like a request coming from a browser.  Your server would not know the difference.

The usual scheme for an API is that you require some sort of developer credential in order to use your API.  You apply terms of service to that credential that describe what developers are allowed or are not allowed to do with your API.

Then, you monitor usage programmatically and you slow down or ban any credentials that are misusing the APIs according to your terms (this is how Google does things with its APIs).  You may also implement rate limiting and other server protections so that a run-away developer account can't harm your service.  You may even black list IP addresses that repeatedly abuse your service.

For APIs that you wish for your own web pages to use (to make Ajax calls to), there is no real way to keep others from using those same APIs programmatically.  You can monitor their usage and attempt to detect usage that is out-of-line of what your own web pages would do.  There are also some schemes where you place a unique, short-use token in your web page and require your web pages to include the token with each request of the API.  With some effort, that can be worked around by smart developers by regularly scraping the token out of your web page and then using it programmatically until it expires.  But, it is an extra obstacle for the API thief to get around.

Once you have identified an abuser, you can block their IP address.  If they happen to be on a larger network (like say a university), their public IP address may be shared by many via NAT and you may end up blocking many more users than you want to - that's just a consequence of blocking an IP address that might be shared by many users.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! My API is just for my web pages to consume, by logged users. I will implement an IP blocking feature but use it only if needed, blocking them in certain cases. For that, I'll monitor all requests, log all abusing events  (when rate limiting is triggered), slow down their connections, and, only if this kind of behavior continues to happen in a sensitive route (if the pattern persists for more than 10 times, for example), then I'll block that IP for some time.

Comment: @FelipeMicali -  Since you're using logged in accounts, it might be better to just block that login rather than that IP.  That prevents accidentally blocking other users who might be sharing the same IP.  But, it doesn't prevent malicious individuals from creating multiple accounts on the same IP.

Comment: Yes, that's my concern. I'll develop a strategy that detects malicious actions in a pattern, and everytime this pattern happens (if the route was reached 10 times in an interval of 10 seconds), I'll register it with a callback from my rate-limiters in a mongodb collection, counting the times those patterns happened for each IP, then I'll block that IP if the pattern exceeds n times. Then, I'll put a middleware in all my routes, after the rate-limiters, to check in my DB if the requesting IP is allowed to proceed.

Comment: Also, those documents will expire after some hours, so the IP won't become blocked forever.